# How to encrypt and decrypt data using memorystream, cryptostream and utf8 encoding correctly?

Tags: c#, encryption

Actually i had wrote the coding for the program in c#, but when the Encrypt Part is empty, i cannot decrypt my encrypted data lonely. It is because my byte[] cipherdata is empty at the earlier part. How can I correct my coding?
I use this program for bigger file. Need it to be faster and precise.

```
    private void buttonEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AesCryptoServiceProvider triple = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        UTF8Encoding u = new UTF8Encoding();            

        triple.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234567890123456");  
        triple.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        triple.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, triple.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);            

        encrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBoxOpen1.Text);
        cs.Write(encrypted, 0, encrypted.Length);
        cs.Close();

        cipherdata = ms.ToArray();
        ms.Close();

        textBoxEncrypt.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipherdata); 
        MessageBox.Show(" Done encrypting ");
    }

    private void buttonDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

        AesCryptoServiceProvider triple = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
        UTF8Encoding u = new UTF8Encoding();
        //MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        //chipherdata = textBox1.Text;

        triple.Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("1234567890123456");          //md5.ComputeHash(u.GetBytes(textBox3.Text));
        triple.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        triple.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(cipherdata);
        CryptoStream cs1 = new CryptoStream(ms1, triple.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);

        //decrypted = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBoxOpen2.Text);

        cs1.Read(cipherdata, 0, cipherdata.Length);
        recipherdata = ms1.ToArray();
        cs1.Close();

        ms1.Close();

        textBoxDecrypt.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recipherdata);
        MessageBox.Show(" Done decrypting ");
    }
```

Comment: UTF8 encoding is good for encoding *arbitrary strings* as a sequence of bytes and reversing that transformation. But the result of encryption *isn't* a set of bytes as might be produced by UTF 8 encoding. There's no guarantee that those bytes resemble *any* particular encoding. `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(cipherdata);` is therefore wrong. If you want to take *arbitrary bytes* and turn them into a string, you need something like *base 64* encoding.

Comment: Also of importance is your choice of block mode (ECB) and padding are... Poor.  Consider CBC and PKCS5/7 instead.  ECB is insecure.

Comment: Is there any way of encoding for arbitary bytes other than base 64 encoding that more suitable for big data? Because for bigger file, the program will be freezed.

Comment: The encoding isn't relevant to why you can't encrypt large files.  It's because they don't fit in memory.  If you implement your stream logic correctly then you won't experience that issue.

Comment: Luke Joshua Park could you give me the correct  encoding for the stream logic?

Comment: If I do the work for you then you won't learn anything.  You should stream `FileStream` input to `CryptoStream` to `FileStream` output.  This will work for files of any size.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had managed to find the solution with easier way.